# python csv output needs header which is missing

Tags: python, csv, cx-oracle

This is a simple code to get the fields from an Oracle table using the Python `cx_Oracle` module.

I found a solution to get the fields from one table and convert the output to csv but has no header.

Here is what I am trying.

1. My csv output needs a header row, what should be the code and where in the below code should I append it?
2. If i want to add one more table (e.g. table is `emp_det`)to get the fields where is the code that should be joint?

Code (edited in from comment):

```
import csv 
import cx_Oracle 
dsnStr=cx_Oracle.makedsn("xxxxxxx","1521","xxxxx") con=cx_Oracle.connect(user="xxxx",password="xxxxx",dsn=dsnStr) 
cursor = con.cursor() 
csv_file = open("employee_data.csv","w") 
writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',', lineterminator="\n", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC) 
cursor.execute("select EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,DEPTNO from RMAN_RPT.EMP") 
for row in cursor: 
    writer.writerow(row) 
cursor.close() 
con.close() 
csv_file.close()
```